# Unrecognized option: -vmargs

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I just downloaded Eclipse Luna 4.4 and added jboss eap 7.1 after installing jboss tools plugin.

While starting the server getting below error:-

```
Unrecognized option: -vmargs
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Java_Home environment variable also set correctly.

Doing all this stuff in Mac OS X El Captain.

Using Java 8 and after changing -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 to 1.8 in eclipse.ini file still getting same error.

Please help me in this.

Eclipse.ini file is below

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use eclipse juno with jboss 5.5

Comment: Jboss 5.5 is having issue with java 8 and I have to use java 8 only as per business requirement